# Getting Null Pointer exception while trying to get value from option in Apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am using JAVA8 and Apache beam 2.19.0 to run some dataflow jobs. As per my requirement I am setting option value dynamically in code as following.

```
option.setDay(ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(sDay))
```

I am trying to get this in another transformation in same dataflow pipeline. When  I run for small data its work fine I am able to get options.getDay().get() value but for huge data such as 5 million lines in different files it is giving Null pointer exception at options.getDay().get().

Adding more example points to this question for better understanding.

1. If I am reading 1 millions of line it execute well.
2. If I am reading 2 millions of line it execute well but give
   Throttling   logger worker. It used up its 30s quota for logs in
   only 25.107s
3. If I am reading more than 2 millions of line it gives Throttling
   logger worker. It used up its 30s quota for logs in only 25.107s and
   Null pointer exception at options.getDay().get()

Comment: Please tell us the language you use. This does not look like python. Is it Java or Go ?

Comment: Thanks I am using java8

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, it looks like you're tying to `setDay` on every element in the stream. I guess that one element is calling `set`, and another element is trying to `get` or `set` again in parallel, which causes the null pointer exception.

To fix this you can pass the `sDay` on the element itself on another property, instead of modifying the options.